# Changing shared preference value to null for other logins

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-sharedpreferences

So my concern is that I am using Shared Preference to store Name in android and can also retrieve the same when logged in again.But, when some other person logs in from the same device, still the name stored is of the previous user. How can I change this and fetch the value of the New user name from firebase? ***P.S I am new to Android***

**Following is my code for Manual Login:-**

```
public class ManualLogin extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

private Button buttonRegister;
private EditText editTextEmail;
private EditText editTextPassword;
private TextView textViewSignup;
private EditText editTextName;

DatabaseReference databaseUsers;

private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

private static final String TAG = "FACELOG";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_manual_login);

    databaseUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users");

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null){
        //profile activity here
        finish();
        startActivity(new android.content.Intent(getApplicationContext(), AccountActivity.class));

}

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);

    buttonRegister = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);
    editTextEmail = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextEmail);
    editTextPassword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextPassword);
    editTextName = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editTextName);

    textViewSignup = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewSignup);


    buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
    textViewSignup.setOnClickListener(this);
}


public void registerUser() {
    String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
    final String name = editTextName.getText().toString().trim();


    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(name)) {

        String id = databaseUsers.push().getKey();

        Users users = new Users(id, name);

        databaseUsers.child(id).setValue(users);

        //Toast.makeText(this, "User Created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


    }else{
        //email is empty
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enter Name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //stop function execution
        return;
    }


    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
        //email is empty
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enter Email id", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //stop function execution
        return;
    }

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
        //password is empty
        Toast.makeText(this, "Enter Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //stop function execution
        return;
    }

    //if validations are fine
    //show progressBar


    progressDialog.setMessage("Registering User...");
    progressDialog.show();


    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                //user is successfully registered & logged in

        //profile activity here
        finish();
        startActivity(new android.content.Intent(getApplicationContext(), AccountActivity.class));

                userProfile();
                Toast.makeText(ManualLogin.this, "Registered Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(ManualLogin.this, "Failed to Register", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            progressDialog.dismiss();


            SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("userName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
            editor.putString("name", editTextName.getText().toString());
            editor.commit();

            //Toast.makeText(ManualLogin.this, "Name Saved", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


        }
    });

}
//set User Display name
private void userProfile(){
    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if(user != null){
        UserProfileChangeRequest profileUpdate = new UserProfileChangeRequest.Builder()
                .setDisplayName(editTextName.getText().toString().trim()).build();

        user.updateProfile(profileUpdate).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){
                    Log.d("Testing", "User Profile Updated");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    if(v == buttonRegister){
        registerUser();
    }

    if(v == textViewSignup){
        //open login activity
        finish();
        startActivity(new android.content.Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));

    }
}
}
```

**Below is the code for AccountActivity:-**

```
public class AccountActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button logout;

private TextView textViewUserName;

private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

private String s;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_account);

    logout = (Button)findViewById(R.id.logout);
    textViewUserName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewUserName);

    // Initialize Firebase Auth
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();





    if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null){
        finish();
        startActivity(new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class));


}

    FirebaseUser sname = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
    textViewUserName.setText("Welcome "+ sname.getDisplayName());






    SharedPreferences sharedPref = getSharedPreferences("userName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    String name = sharedPref.getString("name", "");

    textViewUserName.setText("Welcome "+ name);
logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            mAuth.signOut();

            LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();

            updateUI();
 @Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    // Check if user is signed in (non-null) and update UI accordingly.
    FirebaseUser currentUser = mAuth.getCurrentUser();

    if (currentUser == null) {
        updateUI();
    }

}

private void updateUI() {

    Toast.makeText(this, "You have Logged out", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    Intent accountIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(accountIntent);
    finish();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

when you login that time store data into sharedpreference like below

```
 private void saveData(String value){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("MyData",MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor=sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString("User",value);
    editor.commit();

}
```

In read new user data into firebase database.

```
private void readData() {
    // define only root node.
    mFirebaseDatabase.child("User").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //for(DataSnapshot singleSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            User user = dataSnapshot.getValue(User.class);
            mEtPwd.setText(user.pwd);
            mEtName.setText(user.name);
            mEtEmail.setText(user.email);
            saveData(user.name);
            // }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
        }
    });

}
```

Comment: could you look at the code once and then give a solution as it is really important.